# Avoid reading hidden text from PDF

Tags: text, itext, hidden

I am reading PDF using iText library

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(dir1 + iFileName);

    for(int iCount=1; iCount<=reader.getNumberOfPages(); iCount++){

           String pageText = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, iCount);
           System.out.println(pageText);
 }
```

it is reading hidden text too; can someone please suggest which property I need to set so that it does not read hidden text?

Comment: How is that text hidden? Is it simply outside the page borders? Then filter by area. Is it white on white or rendered invisibly? Then filter by these criteria. Is it covered by some other content? For this you will need to extend the extraction strategy accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have PDF and while reading text from file using Java I am getting text which is not visible to naked eye using PDF reader. But I will try to find how it is made invisible, and follow accordingly.

Comment: Alternatively you may share your pdf file for analysis.

Comment: Hello mkl - can you please suggest how can I send you message having PDF, I tried to find similar on your profile, but couldn't find such option. thanks.

Comment: The best option would be to use a public share on dropbox or google drive and post the URL here. Alternatively you can send it to the mail address you can find in the free text in my stackoverflow profile and I can make it publicly available.

Comment: Can you please download PDF from following link, and help me to find way to read text excluding Hidden text? [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-JlUfbplwmhUjN3QWExeUVNclU/view?usp=sharing [link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each piece of the extra, invisible text in the PDF is drawn starting at coordinates 0,0 (at the lower left) using the rendering mode 3 (neither fill nor stroke text (invisible)).

In that situation one should filter by rendering mode. To do so you have to explicitly set the strategy to a filtered strategy.

The `getTextFromPage` overload you use in your code

```
String pageText = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, iCount);
```

is defined as

```
public static String getTextFromPage(PdfReader reader, int pageNumber) throws IOException{
    return getTextFromPage(reader, pageNumber, new LocationTextExtractionStrategy());
}
```

Thus, you implicitly used the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`. Now you have to filter this strategy, e.g. by replacing that line from your code like this:

```
RenderFilter modeFilter = new RenderFilter(){
    public boolean allowText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo){
        return renderInfo.getTextRenderMode() != 3;
    }
};
TextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(strategy, modeFilter);
String pageText = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, iCount, strategy);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge. I am new to PDF coding, and had no idea what you have shared. +1 but seems I a not eligible to vote yet.

Comment: You can accept the answer (click on the tick at its upper left).